# PHP: I have 2 static functions A and B. How do I bind B to A so that B can only be called within the method A?

Tags: php, function

Ex:

```
<?php

class BLAH {

    public static function A () 
    {
        self::B();
        //Do something
    }

    public static function B()
    {
        //Do something
    }

}
```

Goal: Bind B to A to make sure that B cannot be called elsewhere outside of the static method A.

Comment: Hmmm, `private` instead of `public`?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you want to make `B` either `private` or `protected`, and what you are going for is to make sure `B` can only be called from inside your class.  BUT, if you really want to make sure `B` can only be called from `A`:

```
public static function B()
{
     $trace=debug_backtrace();
     $caller=array_shift($trace);
     if ($caller['function'] != 'A' || $caller['class'] != 'BLAH') {
          throw new Exception('Illegal function invocation');
     }
     else {
         //do something
     }
}
```

Comment: The answer implies as much, but it should be emphasized that, while the code given here is cool and answers the exact question you asked, using `private` or `protected` is almost certainly the right way to go. (I'm not going to say there's **no** good reason to enforce this at the method level, but it would certainly be out of the ordinary.)

Comment: What I realized I wanted was an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Protected method:

```
class BLAH {

    public static function A () 
    {
        self::B();
        //Do something
    }

    protected static function B()
    {
        //Do something
    }

}
```